# PHP Gettext not showing correct language in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, gettext, laravel-5

When I change language the first time it works perfectly. However, when I refresh the page the translation is back to english again, even though the language selector still says "Danish" and getLang returns da_DK.... Then when I run `php artisan cache:clear` it works the first time I refresh, but second time it is back to english again.

Any ideas what could be wrong here?

I am using the package https://github.com/xinax/laravel-gettext to translate. Laravel 5.2.

Answer (score 0):

It is because laravel has it own  'locale' and 'fallback_locale' inthe config file. If you match the language you want, you should be fine.

Ps: I recognize this is an old question, but I was helping just in case...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 5.2 and Xinax/LaravelGetText:

Go to *SessionHandler.php* and change the function to

```
public function get($default)
{
    $locale = $default;

    if (!Session::has($this->sessionIdentifier)) {
        $locale = Session::get($this->sessionIdentifier);
    }

    return $locale;

}
```

For more information you can check http://www.yellowpagesphpscript.com or
http://www.scriptbazar.com